# Properly closing of UDP connection twisted pysnmp

Tags: python, twisted, pysnmp

I make twisted application to send snmp traps using pysnmp. The UDP connections are not closing after execution of sendNotification and after a while application stops working.

Looking to log files after restarting of the application I can see that connections is closing. So I need to add this after sendtrap().

Logs:

```
2017-03-17 09:57:30+0100 [UdpTwistedTransport (UDP)] Stopping protocol <pysnmp.carrier.twisted.dgram.udp.UdpTwistedTransport instance at 0x7fc76365fab8>
2017-03-17 09:57:30+0100 [UdpTwistedTransport (UDP)] (UDP Port 56465 Closed)
```

sendtrap() skeleton

```
from pysnmp.hlapi.twisted import *

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def sendtrap(data):
    connection = UdpTransportTarget((TRAP_DESTINATION, 1620))

    d = yield sendNotification(
        SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData('public'),
        connection,
        ContextData(),
        'trap',
        NotificationType(
            ObjectIdentity('1.1.1.')
        ).addVarBinds() 
    )

    # connection.protoTransport.closeTransport()
```

The only point I found is **connection** instance connection.protoTransport.closeTransport() But this call does not affect for UDP closing.

Do you have any idea how to close UDP?

Answer (score 0):

User Datagram Protocol, or *UDP*, is a stateless / connectionless protocol, and does not need to be closed. You just send it, hope the data ended up at the destination, and forget it.

See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) for more information on UDP.

Comment: I see, but in this case I got  pysnmp.smi.error.MibLoadError: MIB file /opt/sendtrap/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.pyc access error: [Errno 24] Too many open files: and after restarting of application thousand of 2017-03-16 10:29:39+0100 [UdpTwistedTransport (UDP)] Stopping protocol <pysnmp.carrier.twisted.dgram.udp.UdpTwistedTransport instance at 0x7f9af73c7cb0>
2017-03-16 10:29:39+0100 [UdpTwistedTransport (UDP)] (UDP Port 27714 Closed)

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is to preserve `SnmpEngine` instance across `sendtrap` calls. The reason is that SNMP engine is complicated internally and expensive to set up. Here's [an example](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/twisted/agent/ntforg/common-notifications.html#snmpv2c-trap-via-twisted-inline-callbacks).

If you still want to re-initialize SNMP engine from the scratch, then I'd advise you to shut it down explicitly once your call is done:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi.twisted import *
from pysnmp.hlapi.twisted import lcd

def sendtrap(data):

    snmpEngine = SnmpEngine()

    yield sendNotification(
        snmpEngine,
        CommunityData('public'),
        UdpTransportTarget((TRAP_DESTINATION, 1620)),
        ContextData(),
        'trap',
        NotificationType(ObjectIdentity('1.1.1.')) 
    )

    # this will undo all notification-specific changes to SnmpEngine
    lcd.unconfigure(snmpEngine)


# calling Twisted reactor
```

Comment: Hello Ilya,
Unfortunately from pysnmp.hlapi.twisted import lcd is deprecated, and logic putted to protoTransport to closeTransport() which is not working

Comment: @alex could you elaborate on what exactly is not working?